# sqlite3 nodejs get value from table

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I've got the function  getName in my db.js

```
function getName(uid){
    db.all("SELECT name FROM table WHERE uid = ? ",  function (err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(this);
        }
    });
}
```

and I want to get the name and save it to var name in another file.

```
var uid = req.session.user; 

var name = db.getName(uid);
      console.log(name);
```

what is wrong about the db function getname why do I get undefined?
Would be great if you could help me!

Comment: you are returning value from a `async` function

Comment: @CodeBean do I have to make a db.get request ? or how can I get the name from the database?

Comment: i think this will help : https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/blob/master/examples/simple-chaining.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning data from an async function might return undefined as the database request might not have completed on execution of return statement.

```
function getName(uid, callback){
  var query = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE uid = " + uid;
  var name = null;
  db.all(query, function (err, rows) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
      name = rows[0].name;
    }
  });
  return name; <--- this can be execute before db.all() if executed therefore returning null. This is because javascript runs asynchronously.
}
```

The result from database query needs to be passed in a callback or it can be saved in a global variable.

```
function getName(uid, callback){
  var query = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE uid = " + uid;
  db.all(query, function (err, rows) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        callback(rows[0].name);
    }
  });
}
```

In order to execute from another file:

```
function print(name) {
  console.log(name);
}
var uid = req.session.user;
getName(uid, print);
```

Comment: How can I access the name outside the function print?

Comment: declare a global variable username outside print function. var username = '';  In print function do: username = name; As getName is async function accessing username before async completes will result in username set to ''.

Comment: It doesn't overwrite the username variable. When I log the username it's empty! Just how I defined it in the global variable.

Comment: You are accessing the variable before getName finishes its execution. Trying printing the username after setting it to name.

Comment: Wrote console.log(username) after the getName function, but it still calls the log before the print function..?

Comment: yes, console.log(username) after getName is executed before getName is executed. write console.log(username) in print function after username = name;

Comment: But how can I use the variable username then outter the function?