# How do I return a value from a row by querying a sqlite3 database?

Tags: javascript, node-sqlite3

I am writing some database middleware for some expressjs app that is based on sqlite3.
This is my directory structure:

```
     | app
       | database
          index.js
       | routes
          index.js
```

database/index.js contains:

```js
module.exports.getLinkById = function(id) {
    Database.get(`SELECT redir FROM root WHERE id = "${id}"`, [], function(err, rows) {
        try {
            var row = rows;
            console.log(row.redir); // successfully logs the redir attr with correct value
            return row;
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    });
};
```

and routes/index.js contains:

```js
var database = require('../database');
console.log(database.getLinkById("afb8")); // undefined
```

In the database/index.js file, the row based on the id is selected and returned. For debugging, I `console.log()`ged it and that logs the correct value.
However, even thought I returned the `row` value, routes/index.js treats it as undefined.
How do I correctly `return` the value so I can access it in `routes/index.js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an async function that does not return anything.

Simply return a response for express:

```
app.get("/api/user/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    var sql = "select * from user where id = ?"
    var params = [req.params.id]
    db.get(sql, params, (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).json({"error":err.message});
          return;
        }
        res.json({
            "message":"success",
            "data":row
        })
      });
});
```

If you need to run more code alongside it, see:
[sqlite3 nodejs get value from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639056/sqlite3-nodejs-get-value-from-table)

Middleware required function, added to database.js:

```
// Hack to look like node-postgres
// (and handle async / await operation)
db.query = function (sql, params) {
  var that = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    that.all(sql, params, function (error, rows) {
      if (error)
        reject(error);
      else
        resolve({ rows: rows });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Obviously I can do that but how do I implement it in middleware?

Comment: @HackaTunes Unfortunately, sqlite3 doesn't support native async await support, if you need to have a middeware, it has to do async await. Please find a full working example below. You can scroll all the way down.

I also updated my answer to include the most important part of code.

https://blog.pagesd.info/2019/10/29/use-sqlite-node-async-await/